# EC2 DataStax AMI V2.5 Error (Opscenter Cassandra)

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, datastax, ec2-ami, opscenter

I just setup a EC2 cluster and setup a new instance using the AMI: datastax_clustering_ami_2.5.1_hvm.manifest.xml (ami-7f33cd08) on a m3.large Instance type. Followed the instructions carefully and found more people reporting on the same error during the passed few weeks.

On boot, it shows the following error and in the OpsCenter, no nodes are connected. Could this be because the setup is not completed successfully because of the following errors:

```
These notices occurred during the startup of this instance:
[ERROR] 03/06/15-11:46:24 sudo chown opscenter-agent:opscenter-agent /var/lib/datastax-agent/conf:
[ERROR] 03/06/15-11:46:26 sudo chown -R opscenter-agent:opscenter-agent /var/log/datastax-agent:
[ERROR] 03/06/15-11:46:26 sudo chown -R opscenter-agent:opscenter-agent /mnt/datastax-agent:
Exceptions             : 0
Exceptions             : 0
Exceptions             : 0
Exceptions             : 0
Exceptions             : 0
```

The full log:

```
Using username "ubuntu".
Authenticating with public key "imported-openssh-key"
Last login: Fri Mar  6 12:28:22 2015 [*******************************]

Cluster started with these options:
For example: --clustername DSCcluster --totalnodes 1 --version community


Waiting for nodetool...
The cluster is now in it's finalization phase. This should only take a moment...

Note: You can also use CTRL+C to view the logs if desired:
    AMI log: ~/datastax_ami/ami.log
    Cassandra log: /var/log/cassandra/system.log


Datacenter: eu-west
===================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  172.31.30.32  193.04 KB  256     ?       [*******************************]  1a

Note: Non-system keyspaces don't have the same replication settings, effective ownership information is meaningless

Opscenter: http://[*******************************].compute.amazonaws.com:8888/
    Please wait 60 seconds if this is the cluster's first start...


Tools:
    Run: datastax_tools
Demos:
    Run: datastax_demos
Support:
    Run: datastax_support


------------------------------------
DataStax AMI for DataStax Enterprise
and DataStax Community
AMI version 2.5
DataStax Community version 2.1.3-1

------------------------------------


These notices occurred during the startup of this instance:
[ERROR] 03/06/15-11:46:24 sudo chown opscenter-agent:opscenter-agent /var/lib/datastax-agent/conf:
[ERROR] 03/06/15-11:46:26 sudo chown -R opscenter-agent:opscenter-agent /var/log/datastax-agent:
[ERROR] 03/06/15-11:46:26 sudo chown -R opscenter-agent:opscenter-agent /mnt/datastax-agent:
Exceptions             : 0
Exceptions             : 0
Exceptions             : 0
Exceptions             : 0
Exceptions             : 0
```

Edit: the issue is also reported here: https://www.mail-archive.com/user@cassandra.apache.org/msg41111.html

Comment: Did you try actually running the commands in the error?
```sudo chown opscenter-agent:opscenter-agent /var/lib/datastax-agent/conf```
```sudo chown -R opscenter-agent:opscenter-agent /var/log/datastax-agent```
```sudo chown -R opscenter-agent:opscenter-agent /mnt/datastax-agent```

Comment: Yes I did, it stated the username and group did not exist.

Comment: Maybe there's another reason my nodes are not showing up in the OpsCenter. But since someone else had the same issue, my guess is the problem lies in this error.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you can simply uninstall datastax-agents, and then [reinstall](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/5.1/opsc/install/opscManualInstallAgentPkgDeb.html) them from scratch on each node. Self clustering AMI is great, but many times I had issues with it. Plus when you reinstall them manually you may receive more verbose error messages (if you encounter any).

HTH

Roman

Answer (score 0):

The errors you see can be ignored and should not affect any functionality (please let me know if that's not the case).  This is a known issue that can be referenced as OPSC-4825